# Redirect all non www to www except one subdomain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect all URLs not containing `www` to `www`

I used this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Now I need one subdomain not to be redirect like this, or I get an error.

So I'd like to redirect any URL that does not begin with sub or with `www` to `www.example.com`

How can I do this ? thanks

Answer (score 22):

You need a second `RewriteCond`. You can apply as many as you like to a `RewriteRule`.

Assuming anything that is not `sub.mydomain.com` needs to be `www.mydomain.com`, here is your code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

But you can simplify this further using the pipe (`|`) character in Regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(sub|www).mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for that, but it tells me that too many redirects are happening and refuses to open the page... Maybe it's also because before that I'm doing other rewrite for any domain alias to go to main domain ? Example: www.do-main.com goes to www.domain.com. These ones I write explicitly...

Comment: ok, i found it. in your rule, I think the % should be outside the {

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, I was very tired.

Comment: Hi Scott, good answer - you need a forward slash before the $ sign though on the rewriterules, as without it it will redirect sub.example.com/folder to www.example.comfolder

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for picking that up!

Comment: How could this be adapted so that the output URL is ALWAYS using https?

Comment: I also need to know how could this be adapted so that the output URL is ALWAYS using https?

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works for all domains, excluding any subdomains. have fun.

Comment: What about  country code top-level domain com.uk, com.jp? I don't think websites like bbc.com.uk would be fine. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the answer by Scott S but it didn't work, so I modified to use the one I was using for general 301:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And it works like a charm